# How to take unload of a table in informix db when table not having SELECT permission?

Tags: select, permissions, informix

Is there possibility to take unload of a table when the table is `not` having `SELECT` permission.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to unload the table using either the High Performance Loader or the Informix SQL extension `UNLOAD TO file SELECT ...`, then no. You'll need to execute the statement as a user with SELECT privileges.

I'm not in a position to verify what would happen with the `onunload` utility, but I suspect the answer is going to be the same, since I'm pretty sure you need to have elevated privileges (DBA or DBSA) to run that in the first place.

Why do you not have SELECT permission? And if there's a good reason, then you shouldn't be allowed to write the contents of the table to a flat file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use SPL "system" command to unload data from table where your user doesn't has access rights. This command runs as Informix user which DBA by definition. You can see your file system or delete whole your database by using this nice command. There are couple more another methods to do same.

Comment: Only if you can create the SPL as `CREATE DBA PROCEDURE ...`. In which case you don't have the permissions issue in the first place.

Comment: The SYSTEM statement does not run programs as 'informix' on a correctly configured system.  It could only happen when the 'oninit' executable is not SUID root as it is supposed to be and user 'informix' starts the server.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Jonathan's remark. The issue is: if you don't have rights - you don't have rights. I understand the question as:"how to find security whole on incorrectly installed Informix system?"